# How to make an object move towards the mouse position?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make an object to move in an area when clicking the area with the left pointer.

- Is this possible in javascript/jquery?
- Can you please give me some examples if possible?
- I'm aiming to do this in javascript/html/css

Here's an [example of an object following the mouse click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mL8DX.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this ([**Working Demo in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XY8CA/2/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#canvas').click(function(e){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $('#object').css({
            'top': e.pageY-offset.top,
            'left': e.pageX-offset.left
        })
    })
})
```

Whenever the click event happens, it's `pageX` and `pageY` values are taken using which the exact location of the click in the canvas object is found. This coords are then used in jQuery animate function to change the location of the object div in it.

Comment: Dude you rock, i'm going to be trying this out with my idea. Thanks a lot. I'm also going to need help making the sprite have the right animation while moving around the room(If you have ideas please let me know) Best answer answer so far, really helpful Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Well, I guess your sprite will be having 8 pieces of your character in 8 different directions. You need to store the coords of the last clicked point. Now when user clicks on a new point, you need to compare these two points. eg. if y-coordinate is same for both points and x-coordinate is less for newer point, then user clicked exactly above the previous location. I guess that helps

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but your answer could range from moving an object towards the click position by setting its position to absolute in CSS and modifying its left and top position until it reaches the click area with a setInterval timer to elaborate A* path finding.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mousePosition;
var div;
div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = "0px";
div.style.top = "0px";
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.body.appendChild(div);

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        mousePosition = {
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
        };
        div.style.left = (mousePosition.x-div.offsetWidth/2) + 'px';
        div.style.top  = (mousePosition.y-div.offsetHeight/2) + 'px';
}, true);
```